# Pulling out data from a nested Schema

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

so, below is the schema...

```js
const QuestionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    questionBody: { type: String, required: "body"},
    noOfAnswers: { type: Number, default: 0},
    userPosted: { type: String, required: "author"},
    userId: { type: String},
    askedOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
    Comment:[{
        commentBody: String,
        userId: String,
        commentedOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
    }],
    answer: [{
        answerBody: String,
        userId: String,
        answeredOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
        Comment:[{
            commentBody:String,                               ///////
            userId: String,                                   /////// 
            commentedOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now},    ///////
        }]
    }]
})

export default mongoose.model("Questions", QuestionSchema)
```

how do i pull out comment data from the slashed part of the code???
i.e the answer-comment section.

regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull out the comment section of each answer then you can do this:

```
const pipeline: any[] = [
 {
   $project: {
      "Comment": "$answer.Comment",
   }
 }];
const result = await QuestionModel.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: actually, wanted to remove a **particular comment** from a particular **Answer** , just like stackoverflow itself is.